# Symbol changes of commodity futures on Yahoo Finance

Tags: online-data-source, commodities, yahoo-finance, real-time-quotes

I am programming a stock tracker application with Yahoo's finance API. At the beginning of this month I noticed that the information provided by Yahoo on the commodities were wrong. So I looked up the symbols on Yahoo's finance website and realized, that the symbols for the upcoming futures changed.

Due to the fact that I'am not a finance guy, I have no idea what the pattern might be behind the changing commodity symbols. I'am pretty sure that there is a pattern, because the symbols for September are all ending with a **U** (GC**U**16.CMX, SI**U**16.CMX, HG**U**16.CMX etc.).

So we have a monthly changing symbol pattern similar to:

**XX** + **Single letter for the month** + **Year** + **.** + **Exchange**

Does anyone have an idea, in which way the "**Single letter for the month**"-part is changing in the symbol, so that I can automate those one letter changes in my programm?

Comment: Okay, I got it by simply looking up futures from past years.

Comment: Jan = F, Feb = G, Mar = H, Apr = J, May = K, Jun = M, Jul = N, Aug = Q, Sep = U, Oct = V, Nov = X, Dec = Z

Comment: from CME group http://www.cmegroup.com/month-codes.html also note that options month codes are different and depend on put/call type.

Comment: You should post the information you learned as an actual answer.  That is both acceptable and encouraged on StackExchange.